# quotient space of $\Bbb S^3$

Tags: connectedness, quotient-spaces

$\Bbb S^3= \{(x,y,z,w)|x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1\}$ and $(x_1,y_1,z_1,w_1)\sim (x_2,y_2,z_2,w_2)$ iff $w_1>0, \ w_2>0$,

Consider $P: X \to X/{\sim~}$ (natural function). 
I know X is compact then $X/{\sim}$ is compact, and 
X is connected then $X/{\sim}$ is connected.

$\Bbb S^3$ is connected, but $\Bbb S^3/{\sim}$ is not connected..
i don't know what is wrong..(topology:  subspace topology of usual top. on $\mathbb R^4$ and quotient top.)

Comment: This is not an equivalence relation. If $w$ is negative, then reflexivity doesn't hold, right? For example, $(0,0,0,-1) \nsim (0,0,0,-1)$.

Comment: You are welcome!